# How to make editor JS scrollable after some fixed height?

Tags: javascript, html, editorjs

In the **editorjs** I would like to make it scrollable instead of expanding to the bottom (adding new line expend it...). So the editor will take less space on my page.

I am just using the basic version of editorjs

```
const editor = new EditorJS({
    autofocus: true,
    data: dataNote
});
```

Comment: have you tried giving it fixed height and `overflow: auto`?

Comment: I have just try it, it keep it in place, but the line add up under it...

Comment: But the with the overflow it work perfectly! Thanks

Comment: *but the line add up under it*, is that mean that the height is still expanding?

Comment: @SirajAlam no, the original div stay the same height, it the inner div that expend and overflow... but with the overflow auto it make the inner div scrollable

Comment: So, I'm getting some difficulty getting it, it would be great if you could give a code sandbox example of what going on and what behavior you wat.

Comment: It all working with the overflow:auto;

Comment: ok, so seems like my first comment is the answer.